# Is there a way to combine formula?

Tags: google-sheets, sumifs, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I'm making a bonus model for work. There are a lot of article numbers that the sheet has to check.

Right now I'm using this:

```
=SUMIFS(Data!$K$2:$K;Data!$I$2:$I;AA$2;Data!$G$2:$G;$A14)+

 SUMIFS(Data!$K$2:$K;Data!$I$2:$I;AB$2;Data!$G$2:$G;$A14)+

 SUMIFS(Data!$K$2:$K;Data!$I$2:$I;AC$2;Data!$G$2:$G;$A14)+

 SUMIFS(Data!$K$2:$K;Data!$I$2:$I;AD$2;Data!$G$2:$G;$A14)
 etc
 etc
```

Is there a way to combine everything in one Formula? AA2:AD2 doesn't work...

I hope I'm explaining it right :)

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vRO-4tOpgZD97cvDEAjoCz-xK-7YhrjpzRlUBplpXOrwgssE2VYjuzdX3oBZdbNVk924J6La-Vy-52_/pubhtml

Comment: Sorry to much Company data. I don't want to lose my job ;)

Comment: Then change the data Bugs Bunny and friends works well, add random numbers etc etc, but leaving us to guess your challenges tends to mean people will avoid your question.

Comment: not sure if it will work, but you can try `=Sum(ArrayFormula( your AA2:AD2 formula here ))`

Comment: Hello Slai. you mean like this? : =Sum(ArrayFormula(SUMIFS(Data!$K$2:$K;Data!$I$2:$I;AA2:AD2;Data!$G$2:$G;$A17))) - It's not working.

Comment: create a dummy sheet with example dataset and include expected output

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vRO-4tOpgZD97cvDEAjoCz-xK-7YhrjpzRlUBplpXOrwgssE2VYjuzdX3oBZdbNVk924J6La-Vy-52_/pubhtml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm confused with how your data works a bit. But am I right that you want to check for each salesperson if they sold any of the article numbers, and if that's the case sum the column C?

Like so?

[image]

Formula I used translates to:

```
{=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$107=F2)*($B$2:$B$107=TRANSPOSE($E$2:$E$15))*($C$2:$C$107))}
```

And needs to be confirmerd through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: JvdV i wanted to say "i love you" but thats might sound a Little creapy haha. this is exactly what i was searching for the last 3 days! Thank you very much!

Comment: The formula works but everything is very very slow right now. What's going wrong? =ArrayFormula(SUMPRODUCT((Data!$G$2:$G=$A13)*(Data!$I$2:$I=TRANSPOSE(Artikelnummers!$A$2:$A$107))*(Data!$K$2:$K))) This is the formula i'm using.

Comment: @Roy, see how I defined my ranges? `SUMPRODUCT()` and array formulas in general tend to have long process times (it's checking everything against everything to come up with either true or false values). You can check this using the evaluate funtion in excel to trace this. So my advise, specify your range to prevent excel to check the whole column.

Comment: Thanks again. I'm using the normal excel now. This works great!

Answer (score 0):

How about :

```
=SUMIFS(Data!$K$2:$K;Data!$I$2:$I;AA$2;Data!$I$2:$I;AB$2;Data!$I$2:$I;AC$2;Data!$I$2:$I;AD$2;Data!$G$2:$G;$A14)
```

Still trying to find a way to combine criteria...

Well, played and depending what your data is, and if you can control it then something like this may help:

[image]

Comment: The first one is still to much work. We are talking about 200 article numbers... 2nd one Also not possible because al the numbers are different.

Comment: @Roy well, you gave no example data so I had no clue as to what you are working with - you may have only been working with 10 rows... Try reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  And in my second example the numbers are meant to be different... it's about how they are summed...

Comment: Sorry for the bad explanation.

Answer (score 0):

**N9:**

```
=QUERY({A3:C}, "select Col1,sum(Col3) 
                where Col1 is not null 
                group by Col1 
                label sum(Col3)''")
```

**H9:**

```
=TRANSPOSE(QUERY({A3:C}, "select Col1,sum(Col3) 
                          where Col1 is not null 
                          group by Col1 
                          pivot Col2 
                          label sum(Col3)''"))
```

**E9:**

```
=QUERY({A3:C}, "select Col2,sum(Col3) 
                where Col2 is not null 
                group by Col2 
                label sum(Col3)''")
```

**E3:**

```
=QUERY({A3:C}, "select Col1,sum(Col3) 
                where Col1 is not null 
                group by Col1 
                pivot Col2 
                label sum(Col3)''")
```

[image: 0]